# Using pipe and bash commands to find a pattern

Tags: bash

I am trying to learn bash commands to do some useful tricks.

I have a file named `text.txt`. I am trying to use `grep`, `wc -l`, and `pipe` to find out how many lines contain the string `"the"`.

My approach, since I know that pipe uses the output from one command as an input to the other command, was: `grep "the" | wc -l text.txt`

I was thinking to find `"the"` using `grep` and return the lines using `wc -l`. I know my approach is wrong because it doesn't work, and I am now trying to figure out different combinations. Would anyone please explain what the correct approach is?

Thanks!

Comment: Close - `grep "the" text.txt | wc -l` - you need an input file for `grep`, but none for `wc` as it is getting its input from the pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep the text.txt | wc -l`

It's the `grep` command that needs to read the file first, and then you pipe that into `wc`.

However, `grep` also has the line-count built in, so you can shorten it, avoid the extra processes and piping:

`grep -c the text.txt`

Comment: Use `-w` option, like `grep -wc the text.txt` in case you want to match exact words.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are ok with `awk` then try following once.

```
awk '/your_text/{count++}  END{print count}'  Input_file
```